# dynamic routes in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi please I need some help with dynamic routes in Laravel 4, I need to show something like `/denver/` for cities and `/san-francisco/bigburger` for businesses where city are just a few (10) and businesses are like 1000+ records. What is the fastest and more efficient way to do this? If the business in the URL doesn't exist it goes to the city page in the URL.

```
Route::get('/{{ $city_url }}', 'CityController@city');

Route::get('/{{ $city_url }}/{{ $business_url }}', 'BusinessController@biz');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('{city_url}', 'CityController@city');

Route::get('{city_url}/{business_url}', 'BusinessController@biz');

Route::get('{city_url}/{allElse}', 'CityController@city')->where('allElse', '.*');
```

Try the above. Has to be in that order.
Just to add to this, please note 'city_url' and 'business_url' are slugs and NOT urls as their names suggest.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, but how do I efficiently get the records of {city_url} in the city table and {business_url} in the business table??
thanks for the help

Comment: In CityController for example, you could do this: public function city($city_url) { $city = City::where('slug', $city_url)->first(); //...}

Comment: If my answer answered your question, please mark it as 'Accepted'.